# Univariate vs Multivariate meta-regression in metafor

Tags: metafor

I'm performing a meta-analysis using the package metafor.
My data set has 2 moderators.
I have performed univariate meta-regressions for each moderator, using these codes:

> #### Univariate meta-regression model. Moderator: LOCATION
>
> resMeta <- rma(measure="IR",xi=xi, ti=ti, mods = ~ factor(locat), data=metaAAS)

> #### Univariate meta-regression model. Moderator: SUBPOPULATION
>
> resMeta <- rma(measure="IR",xi=xi, ti=ti, mods = ~ (factor(pop), data=metaAAS)

Now I need to perform a multivariate meta-regression.
Is that correct to simply add both moderators to that same function (below)?

> resMeta <- rma(measure="IR",xi=xi, ti=ti, mods = ~ factor(locat)+factor(pop), data=metaAAS)

The code works fine, I just don't know if is technically correct to describe these results as a multivariate meta-regression.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminology in this regard is not fully standardized, but a **multivariate model** typically denotes a model that is used to analyze two or more outcome variables simultaneously. On the other hand, a **multivariable model** is one that includes more than one predictor variable. So you are conducting a multivariable meta-regression analysis, although it is also not common to use that terminology. You can simply say that you are conducting a meta-regression analysis with two (categorical) predictors. And yes, this is fine. You can find a detailed discussion of this type of analysis here:

https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:multiple_factors_interactions